# How to add new provider for django-allauth?

Tags: django-allauth

I'd like to extend `django-allauth` to include other third party OAuth providers (*e.g.*, SurveyMonkey, Qualtrics, etc). I haven't been able to find a good tutorial on how to extend `django-allauth`. Does anyone have any recommendations for how to get started, which classes to write, and how to format/customize URLs for the OAuth flow?

I am already using it to authenticate using Google and Twitter, but I'm finding that many of my users already have accounts on other services that would be more compelling for our use case. Any pointers here would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at this PR, it is adding slack as an OAuth provider.

https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/pull/1410/files